# Validate characters in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application in CI supported Grocery CRUD , but at the time of validation is not recognized , what I need is that a field is validated to accept only alphabetic characters , plus points , comma and space but does not work:

[Function in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQmp3.png)

Lines of code in the function of Grocery CRUD in what I call the function solo_letras:

[Lines of code in method of Grocery CRUD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIW1r.png)

What would be a validation that could take?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in form validation in CodeIgniter.
I do it like this.
At the beginning of your function set all the rules for your form inputs like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputFirstName', 'First Name', required|min_length[4]|max_length[16]|is_unique[users.username]');
```

This is a sample for a user name field.  The first parameter is the form input `name='inputFirstName'`, The second is a readable version of the first and is used for error reporting,  then comes your validations which are separated by the pipe character.  There is a validation for matching regex; `regex_match[/regex/]`.

Place all your validations then use:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            Do something here if validation fails
            return false;
        }
```

To test for validation.
Then continue on with the code if validation passes.

Here is a full sample of a simple registration function:

```
public function register()
    {

        $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputUsername', 'User Name', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[16]|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputEmail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputFirstname', 'First Name', 'required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputLastname', 'Last Name', 'required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputPassword', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]|matches[inputPasswordConfirm]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputPasswordConfirm', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()]));
            return false;
        }

        $username = $this->input->post('inputUsername');
        $email = $this->input->post('inputEmail');
        $firstName = $this->input->post('inputFirstname');
        $lastName = $this->input->post('inputLastname');
        $password = $this->input->post('inputPassword');
        $passwordConfirm = $this->input->post('inputPasswordConfirm');

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $user_id = $this->user_model->insert([
            'username' => $username,
            'email' => $email,
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
            'password' => hash('sha256', $password . PASSWORD_SALT)
        ]);

        if($user_id) {
            $this->session->set_userdata(['user_id' => $user_id]);
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 1]));
            return false;
        }

        $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 0, 'error' => "User not created."]));

    }
```

Comment: I understand but what I need is validation for the field to only accept characters from A to Z in addition to the following characters { [space] . , }

Comment: Sorry, the other one included digits. This is what you want. `/[a-z,A-Z\s\.\,]/g`